# inline scripts not working in laravel livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I am creating a multiple step form with laravel livewire, which is working, but in one of the form I want to apply an inline JS (choices and other js) which was working before I starting with the livewire. see my code below

**panel.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>>
@livewireStyles
@push('styles')  
</head>
<body>
    
     <div>
          @yield('content')
     </div>

    @livewireScripts
    @stack('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

**index.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.panel')
        
@section('title', 'Panel')
    
@push('styles')
  <link href="{{ asset('css/choices.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> 
@endpush
        
@section('content')
        <div class="container">
           @livewire('multi-step-form')
        </div>
@endsection
        
@push('scripts')
  <script src="{{ asset('js/choices.min.js') }}"></script>
  <script>
      const selectStatesInputEl = document.querySelector('#cat');
        if(selectStatesInputEl) {
          const choices = new Choices(selectStatesInputEl); 
        }
  </script>
@endpush
```

I saw this here (https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/inline-scripts#using-js-directive) and I try to re-write my code like this see below but still the same result.

```
@push('scripts')
<script src="{{ asset('js/choices.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>
  document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
    const selectStatesInputEl = document.querySelector('#cat');
      if(selectStatesInputEl) {
        const choices = new Choices(selectStatesInputEl); 
      }
  })
</script>
@endpush
```

Please help with this issue, thanks

Comment: If you are using `@push('scripts')`, then you should also have the corresponding `@stack('scripts')` in your index.blade.php file to push to. See if that helps. Also in which file are you putting the @push part?

Comment: @Coola I have used this `@stack('scripts')` still did not work.

Comment: "Not working" isn't quite helpful. Do you get any errors in the console? What happens, what doesn't happen vs what you expect it to?

Answer (score 0):

delete  `document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {`in new version of livewire js access directly to livewire